# Odd Remainder/Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory

If $n$ is a non-negative integer and $3^n$ is divided by $4$ the remainder is a multiple of $3$

So $$3^n=4k+3$$
From this statement can we imply that $n$ is odd without picking numbers? Can Fermat's little theorem be applied here in some shape despite the fact we are diving by a 4 and not a prime?

Answer (score 1):

First you can't apply Fermat's Little Theorem in this case, becuase the modulo isn't prime number.

Now note that:

$$3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$

So we have:

$$3^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod 4\quad \quad \text{ and } \quad \quad 3^{2k+1} \equiv -1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4; \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$$

So we have:

$$3^n = 4k + 3$$
$$3^n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$$

Using the upper realtion we obtain that $n=2k+1$, i.e. n is odd number.

Comment: How does knowing this $$3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$ get us to $$3^(2k+1) \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$ or $$3^2k \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$ without actually plugging values for n? How do you raise this, $$3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$, to a higher power and know the remainder?

Comment: It's well known property in modular arithmetic that if:

$$a \equiv b \mod c \implies a^n \equiv b^n \mod c$$

Now just change $a = 3$ and $b = -1$

Answer (score 1):

No, but [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) does handle the case when the modulus is not prime.

In this case, $\phi(4) = 2$, so we know that $3^n$ is congruent to $3^2 = 9$ for even $n$ and $3^1 = 3$ for odd $n$.